# Meteor / CollectionFS removes frontend collection contents upon download link click trigger

Tags: javascript, meteor, collectionfs

I'm using Meteor and CollectionFS with S3 to serve both thumbnails and full-size images from the same collection, using different stores. I want to download the full-size image upon a 'dblclick' event.

```
var src = fileRecord.url({
  store: 'images',
  download: true
});

var a = $('<a>');
a.attr('href', src); // canvas.toDataURL(viewerImageObject.original.type);
a.attr('download', fileName); // canvas.toDataURL(viewerImageObject.original.type);
a.appendTo(document.body);
a.trigger('click');
```

Unfortunately, when that event fires, all the items in the frontend collection are removed-- which is rendered with a simple {{#each}} block helper over a cursor returned by a collection.find(). This is not persistent on the backend, only the frontend.

I've [filed a CollectionFS ticket](https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS/issues/720) for this a week ago, and I've been trying to pick this apart to no avail. I also realize I could use FileSaver.js and a Canvas, but that'd get very frontend heavy on mobile and on large images, especially on polyfilled browsers.

How do I prevent the items in my collection from being removed upon downloading an image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**: add *target="_blank"* to your anchor tag, this will make your browser opens a new tab for download link and everything will be fine

**TLDR**

Although I am able to make this worked, I am not sure what is the problem. It looks like that Iron Router will navigate your current tab to the download link you click on(but the url on address bar remains unchanged this makes me wondered), so that all the collections will be gone and your site goes blank